# Wireless headphones for PC without Radio Tuner

Tags: wireless, headphones

I got these [Wireless Headphones Panasonic RP-WF830H](https://www.panasonic.com/middleeast/en/consumer/home-entertainment/headphones/rp-wf830.html) for using them at the PC and they are not working anymore. I can't tune to find the sound.

These work on RF (Radio Frequency) and they have a tuner integrated in it. I can even tune to a few radio stations with them. I don't need the radio tuner, I just need to use them as headphones and when I bought them, I knew nothing about wireless headphones. At that moment, I had no idea that it contains a radio tuner.

Now I want to buy another wireless headphones and I would like to make sure I won't get into the same problem.
For example I noticed these headphones - [MDR-RF895RK RF Wireless Headphones](https://www.sony.com/pk/electronics/headband-headphones/mdr-rf895rk#product_details_default) - how can I make sure they just work and I won't have to waste my time trying to tune the headphones in order to find the sound signal coming from my PC?

Or should I buy Bluetooth wireless headphones? Or maybe infrared wireless headphones? Are they better for using at the PC?

Comment: Get Bluetooth wireless headphones.

Comment: @Tyson: indeed, I never had Bluetooth headphones, I tried one recently and they are really good. It goes through walls, I can move all around the house with the headphones on my ears and still get good signal.